# Running all possible fixed effects combinations for linear mixed effects models

Tags: mixed-model, categorical-data, pca, lme4-nlme, bioinformatics

my data looks like this:

```
> head(df,10)
      ID gene     value   state milk meat veg pruits eggs water
1  ID001    1 0.2044274 healthy    6    1   4      6    1     1
2  ID001    2 0.5214702 healthy    5    1   5      2    6     5
3  ID001    3 0.9340537 healthy    5    6   4      6    1     4
4  ID001    4 0.9579494 healthy    5    5   4      3    5     6
5  ID001    5 0.9815874 healthy    1    5   2      3    1     6
6  ID001    6 0.6312803 healthy    4    5   1      6    5     5
7  ID002    1 0.7388511     ibd    2    5   5      1    6     5
8  ID002    2 0.8470776     ibd    4    1   2      5    1     3
9  ID002    3 0.4771753     ibd    2    2   3      3    5     1
10 ID002    4 0.7780986     ibd    2    2   4      3    4     6
> str(df)
'data.frame':   18 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ ID    : chr  "ID001" "ID001" "ID001" "ID001" ...
 $ gene  : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
 $ value : num  0.204 0.521 0.934 0.958 0.982 ...
 $ state : chr  "healthy" "healthy" "healthy" "healthy" ...
 $ milk  : int  6 5 5 5 1 4 2 4 2 2 ...
 $ meat  : int  1 1 6 5 5 5 5 1 2 2 ...
 $ veg   : int  4 5 4 4 2 1 5 2 3 4 ...
 $ pruits: int  6 2 6 3 3 6 1 5 3 3 ...
 $ eggs  : int  1 6 1 5 1 5 6 1 5 4 ...
 $ water : int  1 5 4 6 6 5 5 3 1 6 ...
```

I want to determine which combination of diets (columns 5 to 10) has the greatest impact on the values of each gene – which model explains the most variance. the main goal is to identify the specific foods that influence gene values (and the sample's state). I used R's `prcomp, fviz_eig, fviz_pca_biplot, lmer`, and lm functions.
any help will be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused as to your data. If ID is the person, then shouldn't each person have the same diet across genes?  How can different genes in the same person have different diets?

Also, from the second part of your post, it looks like you have only 18 people. Is that right?

Comment: In addition, the analysis seems to be devoid of statistical principles and lacks any notion of stability analysis as exemplified [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/hdata.html).